# Can knowledge distillation be used for 3 classes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I have a classification problem (3 classes only) and I trained a teacher-student model.

The trained student model (with knowledge distillation) performs less than the student model trained by itself (without the teacher). I am assuming this is because the information I get from the teacher (the logits from the softmax layer: 0.98 0.02 0 for example) is not very different from the hard labels (1 0 0 for example). Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am thinking of using knowledge distillation using intermediate layers. any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Can you let me know what is the Temeperature value (T) you are using and the size of the student and teacher models?. In theory using intermediate layers may work,

Comment: Hello, my teacher has the same architecture as C3D: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0767.pdf  (8 3d CNN layers), my student has 4 3d CNN layers. I tried different experiments with different temperature values: T = [1,2,4,8,16,30,50]